# jquery change css localstorage - hide div

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I am testing if my localstorage item is set.
That works, the alert message is showing up correctly when it is available or not.
But I would also like to hide a div with ID #QGender.
That is not working, any idea what should be the right way?
I have tried a couple that I have comment here below.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">     
    if("QGender" in localStorage){
        alert('yes QGender is available');
        //$('#QGender').css({"display":"none"});
        //$('#QGender').hide("");
        //$('#QGender').css('background-color', '#323232');
    } else {
       alert('no QGender is not available');
    };
   </script>
```

Comment: Is your script running *after* the DOM has been loaded? And `hide` doesn't take an empty string argument, just use `hide()`

Answer (score 0):

it's not necessary to use $('#QGender').css({"display":"none"}), do this only:

```
$('#QGender').hide();
```